# Google Map not rendering but Markers/Cluster work (grey map area)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps for displaying lot of points of interest on my website but it's actually not working.
The most strange thing is that, in practice, it work because markers and clusters are working correctly and connected actions are working too but the map is not displaying, leaving everything grey in the map area.
The most strange things is that it work correctly from Mobile.

[Here a screenshot of the map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hYTD.jpg)

[Link to the website](http://goo.gl/SXns7X)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-explore">
    <div class="half-col half-map">
        <div class="header-map" id="map"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="half-col half-list">
      ....
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    var center = italy;
    var zoom = 6;
</script>

@if(isset($lat, $lng))
<script>
    var center = {lat: {{$lat}}, lng: {{$lng}}};
    var zoom = 14;
</script>
@elseif(Request::has('lat') and Request::has('lng') and Request::has('formatted_address'))
<script>
    var center = {lat: {{Request::input('lat')}}, lng: {{Request::input('lng')}}};
    var zoom = 14;
</script>
@endif
<script>    
    var markers = [];
    var mapObject;
    function init_map() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: zoom,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(center),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false,
        };
        var marker;

        (function(A) {

            if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
                A.forEach = A.forEach || function(action, that) {
                    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++)
                        if (i in this)
                            action.call(that, this[i], i, this);
                };

        })(Array.prototype);

        mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

        setTimeout(function() {
            update_markers_half();
        }, 1500);

        mapObject.addListener('dragend', function() {
            update_markers_half();
        });
        mapObject.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
            update_markers_half();
        });
    }

    $(window).load(function() {
        $(".container-explore").css("height", $(window).height());
        init_map();
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        $(".container-explore").css("height", $(window).height());
    });

    var geo = $("#city-search");
    $(geo).geocomplete().bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
        mapObject.setCenter(result.geometry.location);
        mapObject.setZoom(13);
        update_markers_half();

    });
    $.fn.geocomplete(geo)

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".minimize-explore").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(".container-explore-list").fadeToggle();
            if($(this).children("i").attr("class") == 'icon-menu') {
                $(this).children("i").attr("class", 'icon-cancel');
            } else {
                $(this).children("i").attr("class", 'icon-menu');
            }
        })
    })

</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.container-explore {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.half-col {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.half-col.half-map {
    height: 388px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

.half-col.half-list {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 105px;
}

.container-explore #map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

i added

```
#map img {
  max-width: none;
  max-height: none;
}
```

and everything worked.